# android service onBind SecurityException

Tags: android, service

I don't know why but in *some devices* my service isn't allowed to bind.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create application mypackage.MyApplication: java.lang.SecurityException: Unable to find app for caller android.app.ApplicationThreadProxy@41680e78 (pid=16805) when binding service Intent { cmp=mypackage/.MyService }
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4394)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:141)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1294)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Unable to find app for caller android.app.ApplicationThreadProxy@41680e78 (pid=16805) when binding service Intent { cmp=mypackage/.MyService }
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1425)
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1379)
        at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.bindService(ActivityManagerNative.java:2720)
        at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1431)
        at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1407)
        at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:473)
        at mypackage.MyApplication.openService(MyApplication.java:151)
        at mypackage.MyApplication.onCreate(MyApplication.java:110)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1000)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4391)
        ... 10 more
java.lang.SecurityException: Unable to find app for caller android.app.ApplicationThreadProxy@41680e78 (pid=16805) when binding service Intent { cmp=mypackage/.MyService }
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1425)
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1379)
        at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.bindService(ActivityManagerNative.java:2720)
        at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1431)
        at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1407)
        at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:473)
        at mypackage.MyApplication.openService(MyApplication.java:151)
        at mypackage.MyApplication.onCreate(MyApplication.java:110)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1000)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4391)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:141)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1294)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**Code from MyApplication:**

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    openService();
    }

public void openService() {
        Intent service = new Intent(this, MyService.class);
        mConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
            @Override
            public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
                mService = IMyService.Stub.asInterface(service);
                if (mListener != null) {
                    mListener.onServiceStarted(mService);
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName cn) {
                mService = null;
            }
        };
        bindService(service, mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE); // 151 line
    }
```

**Manifest:**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="mypackage"
    android:versionCode="25"
    android:versionName="2.3.2" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="7"
        android:targetSdkVersion="16" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> 
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />

    <application
        android:name=".MyApplication"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/CustomTheme"
        android:allowBackup="true" >

        <!-- android:configChanges="orientation" -->
        <activity
            android:name=".ui.activities.NewSearchActivity" 
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <!-- other activities -->

        <service
            android:name="mypackage.MyService"
            android:enabled="true" />

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Please help me! Thank you!

Comment: Did you notice the 'android.os.Parcel.readException'? There might be some problem the way you are parceling the intent extras. Hope the intent extras do not exceed  max size (1Mb).