# SecurityException: Parcel.readException coming from google analytics code

Tags: android, android-intent, google-analytics, google-play-services

Our app is getting quite a few different `SecurityException` reports from our crash report software. Here is a stacktrace of the crash:

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Unable to find app for caller android.app.ApplicationThreadProxy@43fda840 (pid=17925) when registering receiver android.content.IIntentReceiver$Stub$Proxy@43fd9458
     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1431)
     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1385)
     at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.registerReceiver(ActivityManagerNative.java:2466)
     at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiverInternal(ContextImpl.java:1717)
     at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiver(ContextImpl.java:1685)
     at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiver(ContextImpl.java:1679)
     at android.content.ContextWrapper.registerReceiver(ContextWrapper.java:453)
     at com.google.android.gms.analytics.q.v(Unknown Source)
     at com.google.android.gms.analytics.r.cF(Unknown Source)
     at com.google.android.gms.analytics.r.cH(Unknown Source)
     at com.google.android.gms.analytics.s.cO(Unknown Source)
     at com.google.android.gms.analytics.s.cP(Unknown Source)
     at com.google.android.gms.analytics.s.d(Unknown Source)
     at com.google.android.gms.analytics.s$e.run(Unknown Source)
     at java.util.Timer$TimerImpl.run(Timer.java:284)
```

The stack trace is always the same, except the only thing that seems to change is `android.app.ApplicationThreadProxy@41da9030 (pid=9103)` and `android.content.IIntentReceiver$Stub$Proxy@41ee0688` have different numbers on them (is this thread id's or something?)

Now this exception seems to be linked to intent size (see the following links)

- [stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18096607/using-crop-intent-getting-java-lang-securityexception-unable-to-find-app-for-ca)
- [another stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12691149/when-i-send-hashmap-with-size-more-than-20-in-android-4-1-i-get-crash)
- [see the comment on this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13458544/android-service-onbind-securityexception)
- [see b0bs reply here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/YqKnSCNTZYU)

Is this the only cause? If so how is my code causing this when it seems to only come from `google analytics` code? Am I using GA wrong? I  don't seem to be doing much besides making a tracker.

**EDIT**

This is how I am creating my tracker. I have a `singleton` tracker in my application object

```
Tracker appTracker;
synchronized Tracker getTracker()
{
    GoogleAnalytics analytics = GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this);
    if (appTracker == null)
    {
        appTracker = analytics.newTracker([some key]);
        appTracker.enableAdvertisingIdCollection(true);
        analytics.getLogger().setLogLevel(Logger.LogLevel.VERBOSE);
    }


    return appTracker;
}
```

Then in my BaseActivity I have the following code:

```
public void initAnalytics() {

    if (Global.TRACKING_ENABLED) {
        mTracker = app.getTracker();
    }
}

public void sendCommerceData(Map<String, String> params)
{
    mTracker.send(params);
}

public void sendTrackViewData(String _path)
{
    mTracker.setScreenName(_path);
    mTracker.send(new HitBuilders.AppViewBuilder().build());
}

public void sendEventData(String category, String action, String label, long value)
{
    mTracker.send(new HitBuilders.EventBuilder()
            .setCategory(category)
            .setAction(action)
            .setLabel(label)
            .setValue(value).build());
}
```

***EDIT 2***

ok here is the use of sendCommerceData:

```
 sendCommerceData(new HitBuilders.ItemBuilder()
                                        .setTransactionId(Integer.toString(order.orderId))
                                        .setName(orderItem.tradeTitle)
                                        .setSku(orderItem.tradeId)
                                        .setCategory(orderItem.categoryFullname)
                                        .setPrice(price)
                                        .setQuantity(orderItem.quantity)
                                        .build());
```

u_u

Comment: How are you creating the Tracker/sending hits to GA?

Comment: @zaventh see my edited question for the way I send the hits. Im not amazingly happy with the code, but it should be working...

Comment: `sendCommerceData` looks suspicious. Are you sure you are constructing the `Map` correctly to send a valid hit? Any chance you are storing extraordinarily long `Strings` in this custom `Map`?

Comment: Also, what version of Google Play Services are you importing and what is your apps `compileSdkVersion`?

Comment: @JeffMixon google play services is v6.1.11 and compileSdkVersion is 19. 

As for the `Map` it doesnt seem outrageous, see the __Edit 2__ question for more details

Comment: `sendCommerceData` does look fine. However, your Play Services is fairly old. I think the latest is version 6.1.71 now. I'd grab that and see if the issue persists, especially when targeting 19+.

Comment: google play services 6.1.11 was released on Oct 11 I believe, so it's only a month old. I've had this issue for a few months and I keep updating the library and it doesn't solve it. I will update again, but I do not think it is going to help

Comment: Having the same issue. Have you found a solution to this? Thanks.

Comment: @GoranHoriaMihail Afraid not. This is for a project I no longer work on. Hope you figure it out. If you do, please add it here so others can get the help they need.

Answer (score 1):

It's a SecurityException means this is not happening because of our own function. (Mostly system code throw these exception).

and system uses (android.app.ApplicationThread) to register a broadcast.

Unless it is happening on all devices i can say it's because of bad GMS configuration (Google play service).

What you can do is wrap all analytics call with try catch (where you only catch Security exception).

I am not 100% sure but i will add more info after i try it my self.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you are running ProGuard on your application but haven't added the following exceptions to your proguard-rules.txt:

```
-keep public class com.google.android.gms.common.internal.safeparcel.SafeParcelable {
    public static final *** NULL;
}

-keepnames @com.google.android.gms.common.annotation.KeepName class *
-keepclassmembernames class * {
    @com.google.android.gms.common.annotation.KeepName *;
}

-keepnames class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
    public static final ** CREATOR;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately I do have those exceptions in the proguard-project.txt