# How to solve SecurityException: Parcel.readException coming from google analytics code

Tags: android, google-analytics

I have many reports of this bug. I tried several solutions but till now nothing solved it ([see this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26379516/securityexception-parcel-readexception-coming-from-google-analytics-code)). I would like to understand what is going on. Does anybody have a clue about it? I am using v3 of GA.

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Unable to find app for caller android.app.ApplicationThreadProxy@4229d028 (pid=12708) when registering receiver android.content.IIntentReceiver$Stub$Proxy@42132728
    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1472)
    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1426)
    at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.registerReceiver(ActivityManagerNative.java:2563)
    at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiverInternal(ContextImpl.java:1677)
    at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiver(ContextImpl.java:1645)
    at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiver(ContextImpl.java:1639)
    at android.content.ContextWrapper.registerReceiver(ContextWrapper.java:486)
    at com.google.analytics.tracking.android.GANetworkReceiver.register(SourceFile:52)
    at com.google.analytics.tracking.android.GAServiceManager.initializeNetworkReceiver(SourceFile:101)
    at com.google.analytics.tracking.android.GAServiceManager.getStore(SourceFile:184)
    at com.google.analytics.tracking.android.GAServiceProxy.useStore(SourceFile:315)
    at com.google.analytics.tracking.android.GAServiceProxy.connectToService(SourceFile:333)
    at com.google.analytics.tracking.android.GAServiceProxy.access$600(SourceFile:28)
    at com.google.analytics.tracking.android.GAServiceProxy$ReconnectTask.run(SourceFile:415)
    at java.util.Timer$TimerImpl.run(Timer.java:284)
```

Another trace:

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Unable to find app for caller android.app.ApplicationThreadProxy@42ac1ee8 (pid=21543) when registering receiver android.content.IIntentReceiver$Stub$Proxy@42abb9d0
    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1465)
    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1419)
    at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.registerReceiver(ActivityManagerNative.java:2363)
    at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiverInternal(ContextImpl.java:1571)
    at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiver(ContextImpl.java:1539)
    at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiver(ContextImpl.java:1533)
    at android.content.ContextWrapper.registerReceiver(ContextWrapper.java:467)
    at com.google.analytics.tracking.android.GANetworkReceiver.register(SourceFile:52)
    at com.google.analytics.tracking.android.GAServiceManager.initializeNetworkReceiver(SourceFile:101)
    at com.google.analytics.tracking.android.GAServiceManager.getStore(SourceFile:184)
    at com.google.analytics.tracking.android.GAServiceProxy.useStore(SourceFile:315)
    at com.google.analytics.tracking.android.GAServiceProxy.connectToService(SourceFile:333)
    at com.google.analytics.tracking.android.GAServiceProxy.access$600(SourceFile:28)
    at com.google.analytics.tracking.android.GAServiceProxy$ReconnectTask.run(SourceFile:415)
    at java.util.Timer$TimerImpl.run(Timer.java:284)
```

Comment: You got the solution for this ??

Comment: I changed the way the GA is initialized. The app used to have 2 activities, and GA was initialized in the first one. I dropped the first activity and now I don't receive such report anymore.